# Python-Docx Exporting Table to a Word Table

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

i am trying to export a table with dynamic rows (quantity depends on user) to a Microsoft Word table using python-docx
This is my code for the docx:

```
            doc.add_heading("Findings Summary", level=1)
            table_findings = doc.add_table(rows=0, cols=3)
            hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
            hdr_cells[0].text = 'ID'
            hdr_cells[1].text = 'Description'
            hdr_cells[2].text = 'Risk'
            test_id1 = self.InformationOverviewTestIDLineEdit.text()
            for  row_index, row_data in enumerate(c.execute('SELECT Summary_Findings_Name, Summary_Findings_Desc, Summary_Findings_Risk FROM Findings_Summaries WHERE Test_ID=?', [test_id1])):
                row_cells = table_findings.add_row().cells
                row_cells[0].text = (row_data)
                row_cells[1].text = (row_data)
                row_cells[2].text = (row_data)


            doc.add_page_break()
```

This is just the part of the code I need working, I have the rest working flawlessly.
That was my first attempt and I thought that it'd be easier doing that way. 
Essentially, I want to loop the database looking for the Test_ID and extracting all the rows from that Database that contains the Test_ID searched.
This Test_ID will be displayed in Line Edit on my PyQT5 code.
Its the loop part I am struggling with.
If i were to run that code as it is, it returns this error:

> tuple index out of range

```
 line 1080, in Extracting_Report
    hdr_cells1[2].text = 'Risk'
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

EDIT: I have managed to find the issue and this is the new code:

```
            doc.add_heading("Findings Summary", level=1)
        table_findings = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
        hdr_cells1 = table_findings.rows[0].cells
        hdr_cells1[0].text = 'ID'
        hdr_cells1[1].text = 'Description'
        hdr_cells1[2].text = 'Risk'
        test_id1 = self.InformationOverviewTestIDLineEdit.text()
        for  row_index, row_data in enumerate(c.execute('SELECT Summary_Findings_Name, Summary_Findings_Desc, Summary_Findings_Risk FROM Findings_Summaries WHERE Test_ID=?', [test_id1])):

            row_cells = table_findings.add_row().cells
            row_cells[0].text = (row_data)
            row_cells[1].text = (row_data)
            row_cells[2].text = (row_data)
            print(row_data)
```

However, now it prints the row_data but doesnt create the document and it should considering if i remove this block of code it creates a docx document fine

Comment: Add the complete traceback so we can see which line raises the error.

Comment: @scanny sorry, added

Answer (score 0):

A table with zero rows has no cells. Try:

```
table_findings = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that and still get the same error

Comment: I have fixed that error but now got a new one, or the lack of there of